# Using together SelectionChanged event of RichTextBox and TextChanged event of of a comboBox for FontSize throws DependencyProperty.UnsetValue error

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm working on [this](https://wpf-tutorial.com/rich-text-controls/how-to-creating-a-rich-text-editor/) tutorial on the WPF `RichTextBox (RTB)`. Following two events together from that tutorial are throwing the `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` error in the scenario as follows:

**Scenario**: When I change the font sizes of any two words in the `RichTextBox (RTB)`, and the moment I manually select those two words in RTB, I get the `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` error inside the `cmbFontSize_TextChanged(...)` event shown below. But if I remove the `SelectionChanged` event (shown below) of RTB or comment out the last two lines (related to font size) of the SelectionChanged event , the error does not occur.

**Question**: Do we really need the last two lines (related to font size) of the following `SelectionChanged` event -  or, how else we can resolve the issue? I tested that without those two lines, the app successfully changes the font size of any selected text (even if it has words with different font sizes) and does not throw the `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` error inside  `cmbFontSize_TextChanged(...)` event.

**Remark**: I have uploaded the minimal example [here](https://ufile.io/6t4on07s) for this scenario. How to test: On RTB, copy/paste: `Word1 and Word2 in one sentence.` Change the size of Word2 to different size (say, 16). The moment you select `Word1 and Word2` part, you will get the following error:

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp_Test4RTB.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_Test4RTB"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="Font Size:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cmbFontSize" Width="50" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cmbFontSize_TextChanged" />
        </ToolBar>
        <RichTextBox Name="rtbEditor" SelectionChanged="rtbEditor_SelectionChanged" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmbFontSize.ItemsSource = new List<double>() { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 36, 48, 72 };
    cmbFontSize.SelectedIndex = 4;
}

private void rtbEditor_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty);
    btnBold.IsChecked = (temp != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) && (temp.Equals(FontWeights.Bold));
    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontStyleProperty);
    btnItalic.IsChecked = (temp != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) && (temp.Equals(FontStyles.Italic));
    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
    btnUnderline.IsChecked = (temp != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) && (temp.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline));

    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontFamilyProperty);
    cmbFontFamily.SelectedItem = temp;
    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontSizeProperty);
    cmbFontSize.Text = temp.ToString();
}

private void cmbFontSize_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    rtbEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, cmbFontSize.Text);
}
```

Comment: The FontSize property is of type double.
And you are assigning string to it.

Comment: @EldHasp `cmbFontSize_TextChanged(...)` event works fine if I comment out the last two lines of `rtbEditor_SelectionChanged(...)` event. It's the exact same code as in the famous WPF online tutorial linked in my post above. However there may be something there that either I am not understanding or that tutorial is missing.

Comment: I see no reason to analyze in this topic - this is a mistake in the tutorial that you watched, or you misunderstood it.
For the reasons for your problem and how to solve it - I have provided clarifications in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the event.

You want to assign a value of type string to the double property.
Try to do `double num =" 12.34 ";` in the code - there will be an error.
You are trying to do the same here.
Actually in the error message its reason is written in detail.
Before assigning a string to a numeric variable or property, it must first be converted.

But in your task, this is pointless, since you are fetching values from a double collection.
It is only necessary to check whether a choice was made and, if so, then assign the selected value.

```cs
private void cmbFontSize_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbFontSize.SelectedItem is double number)
        rtbEditor.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, number);
}
```